# How to Style the Selected PivotItem Header

Tags: windows-phone-8, pivotitem

I am trying to implement a solution whereby the currently selected PivotItem Header Background is the PhoneAccentBrush, but all of the other pivot headers are a default color such as PhoneDisabledBrush. This way when the user swipes left or right, a PivotItem will come into view and its background color will change to the active PhoneAccentBrush, and all other pivot headers will remain with the default background color. How might I be able to do this?

Currently I have implemented what I want, except for the selected/nonselected pivot item backgrounds

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="PivotStyle1" TargetType="phone:Pivot">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <!--<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>-->
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="white"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Grid/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="phone:Pivot">
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" CacheMode="BitmapCache" Grid.RowSpan="2" />
                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CacheMode="BitmapCache" Grid.Row="2" />
                        <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding TitleTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Title}" Margin="24,17,0,-7"/>
                        <Primitives:PivotHeadersControl x:Name="HeadersListElement" Grid.Row="1"/>
                        <ItemsPresenter x:Name="PivotItemPresenter" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="2"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

...

<!--Pivot Control-->
<phone:Pivot x:Name="Pivot" Style="{StaticResource PivotStyle1}">
    ...
</phone:Pivot>
```

Which looks like..

[image]

*Update

StackTrace Exception in the following update.. `InvalidOperationException: Cannot resolve TargetProperty (Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color) on specified object.`

```
<Style x:Key="PivotHeaderItemStyle1" TargetType="Primitives:PivotHeaderItem">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="21,0,1,0"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Primitives:PivotHeaderItem">
                    <Grid>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unselected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="myback" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="DarkGrey"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="myback" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Red"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="myback">
                            <ContentControl x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Opacity="{StaticResource PhonePivotUnselectedItemOpacity}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="PivotStyle1" TargetType="phone:Pivot">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Grid/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="phone:Pivot">
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.RowSpan="3"/>
                        <ContentControl x:Name="TitleElement" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding TitleTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Title}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="24,17,0,-7" Style="{StaticResource PivotTitleStyle}"/>
                        <Primitives:PivotHeadersControl x:Name="HeadersListElement" Grid.Row="1" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource PivotHeaderItemStyle1}"/>
                        <ItemsPresenter x:Name="PivotItemPresenter" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="2"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Do you mean something like this? http://i.imgur.com/zEzCFGp.png

Comment: Similar although no margins between pivot items, and only the active pivot will have a background color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

K, seems you're getting there.  The actions need to avoid code behind....

We're just going to add another storyboard animation for the background.  And the simplest way I know how to do this is just add a border.

Add a Border around your < ContentControl x:Name="contentPresenter" />  so it looks like this

```XAML
<Border x:Name="myback" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
    <ContentControl x:Name="contentPresenter"/>
</Border>
```

Now lets color it based on the Selected State.  Add in your other Storyboard animations as well.

```XAML
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
        <VisualState x:Name="Unselected">
            <Storyboard>
               <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="myback" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="DarkGrey"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
            <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="myback" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Red"/>
           </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

---

Let me know it goes well :D

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have updated my original post. I am getting an error stating `InvalidOperationException: Cannot resolve TargetProperty (Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color) on specified object.`

Comment: I'm so sorry, I typed in the wrong <Border>  it's prose to be <Border x:Name="myback" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">, I edited my solution.

Comment: Question in coming back to this implementation, the `Border` property does not contain `Foreground`, so how can I update this to be able to change the foreground of the selected and unselected header items as well?

Comment: I'v updated a link to my new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26692826/how-to-style-pivotitem-header