# How to Style PivotItem Header

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I have an existing Pivot header template I am using, but it is not giving me the effect I need. I need the currently selected PivotItem to have a blue foreground and white background, while all other pivot items have a standard disabled foreground and background look. Currently below I have what I believe is everything except the blue foreground on the selected PivotItem, but I cannot figure out how to apply a foreground correctly to only the selected item?

[image]

```
<Style x:Key="PivotHeaderItemStyle1" TargetType="Primitives:PivotHeaderItem">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="21,0,1,0"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Primitives:PivotHeaderItem">
                    <Grid>                          
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unselected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="myback" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledColor}"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="myback" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundColor}"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>                            
                        <Border x:Name="myback" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentControl x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Opacity="{StaticResource PhonePivotUnselectedItemOpacity}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="PivotStyle1" TargetType="phone:Pivot">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Grid/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="phone:Pivot">
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.RowSpan="3"/>
                        <ContentControl x:Name="TitleElement" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding TitleTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Title}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="24,0,0,-7" Style="{StaticResource PivotTitleStyle}"/>
                        <Primitives:PivotHeadersControl x:Name="HeadersListElement" Grid.Row="1" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource PivotHeaderItemStyle1}" FontSize="70"/>
                        <ItemsPresenter x:Name="PivotItemPresenter" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="2"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `<ContentPresenter>` to a `<TextBlock>`

Like so

```
<Style x:Key="PivotHeaderItemStyle1" TargetType="Primitives:PivotHeaderItem">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,0,10,0"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Primitives:PivotHeaderItem">
                <Grid>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unselected">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="border_highlight" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Transparent"/>
                                    <ColorAnimation  Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Green"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation  Duration="0:0:1" Storyboard.TargetName="border_highlight" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="PaleGreen"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter"/>
                                    <ColorAnimation  Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Blue"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Border x:Name="border_highlight" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" >
                        <!--<ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Opacity="{StaticResource PhonePivotUnselectedItemOpacity}"/>-->
                        <TextBlock x:Name="contentPresenter" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Opacity="{StaticResource PhonePivotUnselectedItemOpacity}"></TextBlock>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Then you can animate the Foreground.  Here's a screenshot of the above code.  With Selected Color = Blue and Unselected Color = Green.  You will need to add back in your background animation though.

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks that worked great. On another note, when messing with these PivotHeader items I lost the original pivotheader textblock format style. How can I get that back instead of the thicker looking text in my screenshot?

Comment: Nevermind with your implementation I added `Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" FontSize="70"` within the new TextBlock and I believe it worked., for anyone else's future reference.

Comment: @Matthew np, always willing to help someone making a WP program beyond the generic layout that most programs use.  As for the Font you can set it in the `<TextBlock>`, Set it as `<Setter Property="FontSize" Value="40"/>` in the PivotHeaderItemStyle1, or you can even set it in the `<Primitives:PivotHeadersControl>`, It will get pass down where ever you defined it in the hierarchy. :)

Comment: I tried using this with UWP in Windows 10, and it didn't want to build with Primitive: tag before PivotHeaderItem, so I removed that tag, and now it breaks when ever I try to debug it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

@Teysz, I think that with Windows 10 UWP you better start from the default style for PivotItemHeader and make a copy of that in the ..Resources section of your XAML file. The default style cannot be inserted by Visual Studio 2015 so you have to get it yourself from:
`%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\10.0.10240.0\Generic\generic.xaml`
I found this at http://blog.hompus.nl/2015/09/04/responsive-pivot-headers-in-universal-windows-platform-apps/

Comment: Great, @jos-huybrighs. I'll try that later today! Thank you.