# How can I add a botton on the right side of the Pivot Header

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am working on an app on Windows phone 8.1.
I have a Pivot control in my app. What I want is to add a Button on the right side of the Pivot Header.
So basically, I want the button to overlay the Pivot Header of the Pivot Control.

So I go and edit template for the Pivot Control, 
I add '' under PivotHeaderPanel but nothing shows up. I tried to move that to inside "PivotHeaderPanel ", but the xaml compiler gives me warning.

Is there a way to achieve what I want?

```XAML
 <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" HorizontalSnapPointsAlignment="Center" HorizontalSnapPointsType="MandatorySingle" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="1" Template="{StaticResource ScrollViewerScrollBarlessTemplate}" VerticalSnapPointsType="None" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" ZoomMode="Disabled">
    <PivotPanel x:Name="Panel" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <PivotHeaderPanel x:Name="Header">
            <PivotHeaderPanel.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform x:Name="HeaderTranslateTransform" TranslateX="0"/>
            </PivotHeaderPanel.RenderTransform>
        </PivotHeaderPanel>
        <Button Content="MyBotton" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
        <ItemsPresenter x:Name="PivotItemPresenter">
            <ItemsPresenter.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform x:Name="ItemsPresenterTranslateTransform" X="0"/>
            </ItemsPresenter.RenderTransform>
        </ItemsPresenter>
    </PivotPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: I can't believe they messed with Pivot in 8.1 :/, can you edit the template of that `<PivotHeaderPanel>`?

Comment: How can I do that? I went to Document Viewer and select 'Pivot' and 'Edit Template', How can I edit the template of PivotHeaderPanel?

Comment: it used to be called `<Primitives:PivotHeadersControl>` and you can edit the template for that.  I made tons of changes to it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26692826/how-to-style-pivotitem-header/  but it seems 8.1 uses a different template.  That is why I was surprised they messed with it.

Comment: Thanks. Now I only see they have a <PivotHeaderPanel x:Name="Header">. But how can I edit the template for that? I don't see any template for <PivotHeaderPanel x:Name="Header">. Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried editing the template for that control, but it looks like it doesn't have one.  The best option then is to insert the button like you did.  Only difference is, I overlay the button over the header using their top container grid.  Like so:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" HorizontalSnapPointsAlignment="Center" HorizontalSnapPointsType="MandatorySingle" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="1" Template="{StaticResource ScrollViewerScrollBarlessTemplate}" VerticalSnapPointsType="None" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" ZoomMode="Disabled">
    <PivotPanel x:Name="Panel" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <PivotHeaderPanel x:Name="Header">
            <PivotHeaderPanel.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform x:Name="HeaderTranslateTransform" TranslateX="0"/>
            </PivotHeaderPanel.RenderTransform>
        </PivotHeaderPanel>
        <ItemsPresenter x:Name="PivotItemPresenter">
            <ItemsPresenter.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform x:Name="ItemsPresenterTranslateTransform" X="0"/>
            </ItemsPresenter.RenderTransform>
        </ItemsPresenter>
    </PivotPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
<Button x:Name="myButton" Content="MY BUTTON" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right"></Button>
```

---

Preview of Style

[image]