# Windows Phone 8 edit header pivot page

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, datatemplate

I'm create WP application and want create next design pivot page:
[Pictures](http://1drv.ms/1o6utLP)

I'm find xaml style code, but it's not something that I need.

```
    <Style x:Key="MainPivotStyle" TargetType="phone:Pivot">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Grid />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="phone:Pivot">
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid Grid.RowSpan="2"
                          Background="DodgerBlue"
                          CacheMode="BitmapCache" />
                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="0"
                                      Margin="24,17,0,-7"
                                      Content="{TemplateBinding Title}"
                                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding TitleTemplate}" />
                    <primitives:PivotHeadersControl x:Name="HeadersListElement" Grid.Row="1" />
                    <Grid Grid.Row="2"
                          Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                          CacheMode="BitmapCache" />
                    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="PivotItemPresenter"
                                    Grid.Row="2"
                                    Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Tell me how to do this style?

Comment: Your question is not clear, if you could even call it a question.

Comment: @ChubosaurusSoftware I want to change the style of the active item pivot page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ChubosaurusSoftware I want to change the style of the active item pivot page.

If that is the case, I already answered this.  You got the only the partial `Templates` that are need.

See [How To Style A Pivot Item Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26692826/how-to-style-pivotitem-header/26693097#26693097).  It is a full solution to change the background/foreground of the Selected Pivot Header.  Noticed the `Storyboards`

You will need the primitive controls namespace if you're modifying the Header Template

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    xmlns:Primitives="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Primitives;assembly=Microsoft.Phone" x:Name="phoneApplicationPage">
```

Useful SO Links

[How to Style the Selected PivotItem Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25476577/how-to-style-the-selected-pivotitem-header/25479068?noredirect=1#comment41981200_25479068)

---

If you need more help, then what are you trying to Style your Pivot Header to?  That image with the bottom border for the SelectedItem?

Comment: Thanks you @Chubosaurus Software. I'll try to do it.